# Issues when defining methods for `[` and `[[` in a package

Tags: r, package, brackets

I have the following method part of a package (the code itself is not important):

```
#' Improved vector subsetting
#'
#' @param x a composer_vector
#' @param i standard indices used to subset
#' @param ... predicate subsetting functions applied on top off subset by indices
#' @export
#' @examples
#' vec <- co("A hello", "B hi")
#' vec[,~startsWith(.,"A")]
#' vec[1:2, ~startsWith(.,"A")]
#' vec[startsWith ="A"]
`[.composer_vector` <- function(x, i, ...) {
  x  <- unco(x)
  if (!missing(i)) x <- x[i]
  fs  <- list(...)
  if (length(fs)) {
    fs <- harmonize_funs(fs,NULL)
    x <- x[purrr::reduce(fs,~.y(x) & .x, .init = TRUE)]
  }
  co(x)
}
```

I can document, build and install the package without issue, using:

```
devtools::document()
pkg_path  <- devtools::build()
install.packages(pkg_path, repos = NULL, type="source",clean=TRUE)
```

but when I attach the package, the method is not exported (not accessible with `::`, though accessible with `:::`), and is not called when I use it on an object of the appropriate class.

If I rename it to `foo` all goes well and `foo` is exported.

I have the same issue when defining a method for `[[`.

If it works for `data.table` , why doesn't it work for me?

---

*the full package code is on [github](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/composer) and this code in particular is located in [brackets.R](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/composer/blob/master/R/brackets.R)*

Comment: Because data.table doesn't use Roxygen

Comment: Is the package source publicly accessible, e.g. in a GitHub repo?

Comment: I uploaded all on github, see the end of my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the function is not exported in your `NAMESPACE` file. The `@export` tag will only help you with your `NAMESPACE` file if it does not exist when you run `devtools::document()`; if you already have a `NAMESPACE` file when you `document()`, you'll get the warning

> Warning: The existing 'NAMESPACE' file was not generated by roxygen2,
>   and will not be overwritten.

Your `NAMESPACE` has

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

This is normally fine, because usually you only have functions (that you want exported) that begin with a letter. However, here you want functions exported that begin with `[`, which this will not do. So, if you delete your `NAMESPACE` file and re-run `devtools::document("composer/")`, and reinstall the package, a new `NAMESPACE` will be written that properly exports all functions, including your extract methods:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method("[",composer_vector)
S3method("[[",composer_vector)
export(..)
export(co)
export(compose2)
export(unco)
```

Then the following works just fine:

```
library(composer)

vec <- co("A hello", "B hi")
vec[,~startsWith(.,"A")]

# [1] "A hello"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "composer_vector" "character"      

vec[startsWith ="A"]

# [1] "A hello"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "composer_vector" "character"
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Glad it helped!